# gwt compiling error

Tags: gwt

```
Compiling module com.sem.Sem10
   Finding entry point classes
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.sem.client.Sem10'
         [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
         [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
```

My package structure is

- com.sem
- com.sem.client
- com.sem.schema
- com.sem.server

  inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'
    inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'
    inherits name='com.google.gwt.maps.GoogleMaps'
    script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?gwt=1&file=api&amp....
    entry-point class='com.sem.client.Sem10'
    source path='com.sem.schema'

I have googled this thing for quite a while and could not find a solution...? any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your source path is incorrect.

If you set it to com.sem.schema then the com.sem.client won't be on the source path, and therefore your entry point com.sem.client.Sem10 won't be either.

Try removing your source path definition, use the default (which is the client subpackage underneath where the Module XML File is stored - so com.sem.client).

See here for more information: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules

Comment: Mind you, if you really do want to use classes from com.sem.schema on the client, you'll need to explicitly add both packages to your source path.

Comment: good point tdavies.  you can have multiple <source > elements, see here for further explaination: http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&s=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&t=DevGuideModuleXml

Answer (score 0):

Here's another suggestion to correct your source path in the *.gwt.xml file if you don't want to use the default.

- In your .gwt.xml file, find the source tags near the bottom of the file.

  revert to an earlier working commit, or open a known working project

  take note of the pattern that the working source tags follow relative to the package structure of your working project.

  roll forward to the broken commit

  modify your source tag(s) to correspond to the current package structure, following the same pattern.