# GWT not compiling with sub-packages

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT and tried to make an application where the client and server classes shared some beans and functionality classes. Here is the package structure:

com.myGWT.client
com.myGWT.server
com.myGWT.shared

The `shared` package has classes used by *both* the `client` and `server` package classes.

I've added the following to my module file:

`<source path='client'/>`
`<source path='com.myGWT.shared'/>`

The GWT compiler says it can't find the code for the classes in `shared` package.

I've tried moving `shared` into `server` package to make it `com.myGWT.server.shared`. A class from `client` uses a class from `shared` and GWT says 
`No source code is available for type...`

I've referred [gwt compiling error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962933/gwt-compiling-error) but couldn't figure my stuff out :(

Could someone please help.

Thank you

Comment: also referred <http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules>

Comment: Also when you use eclipse to create a new project it will setup a project with the package layout you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I've been stupid enough to develop on GWT like any other framework. My client code was using external JARs and they require to be inherited in the main modul for GWT. I didn't know this.

All code using external JARs moved to server side.

Answer (score 2):

put the gwt.xml file in src/com/myGWT/ directory and then all you need is

```
    <source path='client' />
    <source path='shared' />
```

Also the path uses / not . between directories.

Comment: Yes I used Eclipse to create a new project and it gave me the shared package. But a class in the client package wants a class in the shared package, which it cannot find. Also, the .gwt.xml file is under src/com/myGWT/